# Result of encodeURIComponent not being decoded correctly on server-side

Tags: javascript, php, urlencode

I'm struggling to correctly encode/decode a JSON string for sending via query string in a GET request.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function executeRequest(applyUriEncode) {
                var json = '{"foo":"⚡&❤很久很久以前"}';
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open('GET', 'https://example.com/test.php?json='+(applyUriEncode ? encodeURIComponent(json) : json), false);
                
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        console.log("applyUriEncode: "+(applyUriEncode ? "true\n" : "false\n"));
                        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText+"\n");
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onClick="executeRequest(true);">Submit encoded</button>
        <button onClick="executeRequest(false);">Submit unencoded</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php // test.php
echo $_GET['json'];
```

Output when clicking `Submit encoded` and `Submit unencoded`:

```
applyUriEncode: true
{"foo":"ðŸ’€ðŸ•âš¡ðŸ’Ž&ðŸŽâ¤å¾ˆä¹…å¾ˆä¹…ä»¥å‰"}

applyUriEncode: false
{"foo":"⚡
```

Desired output is

```
{"foo":"⚡&❤很久很久以前"}
```

I need to encode the JSON because otherwise, special characters such as `&` will break the string. However, the result of `encodeURIComponent` does not seem decoded correctly by PHP. I tried `urldecode` on the server side, but that didn't change a thing (output remains the same).

I feel this is a fundamental question, and it should have an answer somewhere here on StackOverflow, but I couldn't find it. I found tons of questions with similar problems, but none led me to a solution for this specific problem.

---

**Edit:**
Inspired by the apparently AI-generated reply posted by @Adarsh Pattnaik I played around with ChatGPT a bit myself. After a few attempts, it suggested to add `<meta charset="UTF-8">` to the HTML. This did indeed yield the correct output.

However, I don't understand why. The HTML file itself was always encoded as UTF-8. Request and response headers sent/received to/from test.php are (and always were) of content-type `text/html; charset=UTF-8` as seen on the network tab of Chrome. Content-type of the HTML is `text/html` (without `charset=UTF-8`) and this didn't change when adding the `meta`-directive.

So what difference does `<meta charset="UTF-8">` make that it now yields the correct result?

Comment: Maybe use the utf8_decode function in PHP to decode the UTF-8 string first? echo utf8_decode($_GET['json']);

Comment: Output: `{"foo":"�???�?�?�?��???&�??�❤�?�?�?�?以�?�"}`

Comment: Hrm, utf8_decode only works with ISO-8859-1 encoded strings. If your string contains characters that are not represented in ISO-8859-1, you might need to use the mb_convert_encoding function instead: echo mb_convert_encoding($_GET['json'], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');

Comment: Output: `{"foo":"Ã°Å¸ââ¬Ã°Å¸Ââ¢Ã¢Å¡Â¡Ã°Å¸âÅ½&Ã°Å¸Å½ÂÃ¢ÂÂ¤Ã¥Â¾ËÃ¤Â¹â¦Ã¥Â¾ËÃ¤Â¹â¦Ã¤Â»Â¥Ã¥â°Â"}`

Comment: Using `fetch` and `POST` for the method this yields the desired response when I wrote a test page...

Comment: You should do some basic tests to figure this out. If you enter `https://example.com/test.php?json=%C3%9F` in your browser, do you see `ß`?

Comment: @Olivier: I do. Also, it doesn't really matter if I put a URL encoded string into the query or an unencoded string. The browser converts it automatically to url encoded.

Comment: OK, then how about `https://example.com/test.php?json=`?

Comment: SO never ceases to surprise me. This time it is encoding emoticons to be url safe . Why not just use a post request? The body of the `post` request will give you great relief even if you want to upload the entire Arabic dictionary.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon Sure, POST would be more appropriate for this, but GET should work.

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering is related to character encoding. When you use `encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript, it correctly percent-encodes the JSON string, including the Unicode characters. However, when PHP receives the query string, it does not automatically decode the percent-encoded Unicode characters back to their original form.

To fix this, you need to ensure that PHP is interpreting the incoming data as UTF-8 and then use `urldecode` to decode the percent-encoded string. Here's how you can modify your PHP code to achieve the desired output:

```
<?php // test.php

// Get the raw, percent-encoded JSON string from the query parameter
$encodedJson = $_GET['json'];

// Manually decode the percent-encoded string
$decodedJson = urldecode($encodedJson);

// Ensure that the string is treated as UTF-8
$decodedJson = mb_convert_encoding($decodedJson, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

// Output the decoded JSON string
echo $decodedJson;
```

This code snippet assumes that your PHP environment is configured to use UTF-8 as the default character encoding. If it's not, you might need to explicitly set the character encoding to UTF-8 using `mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8')` at the beginning of your script.

Additionally, it's important to note that when you're sending JSON data in a query string, you should always use `encodeURIComponent` to encode the JSON string. This is because the query string has certain reserved characters (like `&`, `=`, `+`, `?`, etc.) that can break the structure of the URL if not encoded. The `encodeURIComponent` function ensures that these characters are safely encoded so that they do not interfere with the URL's format.

On the client side, your JavaScript code is correct in using `encodeURIComponent` when setting the `applyUriEncode` flag to `true`. Always use the encoded version for sending data in a query string to avoid issues with special characters.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! However, it doesn't work. Output is `{"foo":"ðŸ’€ðŸ•âš¡ðŸ’Ž&ðŸŽâ¤å¾ˆä¹…å¾ˆä¹…ä»¥å‰"}`. 
FWIW: I take the output from the console window in Chrome. Request and response headers specify content-type `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @AlexanderTobiasBockstaller *"Thank you for your contribution"* You mean ChatGPT's contribution.